How does Luigi affect your chance of rolling bigger numbers?
When you get Luigi as a buddy in Super Mario Party Jamboree, the game says his ability is:

When you hit a dice you'll have an easier time rolling bigger numbers.

How exactly does Luigi's ability work when you roll a dice? Is it like a weighted dice? If so, how much more likely are you to roll higher numbers?

Screenshot courtesy of Alpharad

After rolling all your dice on your turn Luigi will attempt to nudge the dice. If he succeeds the value of the dice is set to 10, else it stays the same as before.
If you rolled two or three dice in your turn and he succeeds all dice will change to a 10. You will thus also get the doubles / triples bonus coins.
The specific chance of the ability triggering is unclear but it seems to be around 33%.

Image source

Where did you get that info from?

When the game launched people on a multiplayer-focused Discord server tested it out in more detail, specifically the estimated 33% chance.  Here's a link to a Youtube video showing Luigi nudging a dice.

This is also discussed on this Reddit: "Luigi: About a 1/3 chance to roll a 10"
